# How to realize a google play billing subscription in an open source app?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I'm researching for developing an open source app that will get a sync feature in future.

This will be realized with Firebase Firestore. This feature should only be available to users subscribing to an abonnement via Google Play Billing.

Now, if I upload my `google-services.json` to my open source repo, anyone can compile the app and remove the check, whether there's an active subscription or not.

But if I don't upload my `google-services.json`, CircleCI can't build my project, since the file is missing.

Does anyone have experience in this matter, or some tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use a public repo/public build server for private info like `google-services.json`. Use fake data for the public repo. See: https://www.droidcon.com/news-detail?content-id=/repository/collaboration/Groups/spaces/droidcon_hq/Documents/public/news/android-news/Configure%20Firebase%20Project%20for%20Continuous%20Integration%20Builds

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should have a server for this. firebase or custom, doesn't matter, but the purchase, subscription, and renewal business rules should not be in your app providing the services based on the subscription status.

If all of the logic is in your app, without server, then you're bound to have issues with this. There's no way around that.
You should also assume that somebody **will** break your subscription logic (to provide free access) and the apk will be listed forever on something like apkmirror for anyone to get it.

Here's a suggested proper flow.

Server:

- users need to have a login
- have a list of products a user can subscribe to, with SKUs
  that exist in the google play store, under your app's products

App:

- app calls your server to get a list of products available for this user. you really care about getting the SKUs for this.
- make request to google's billing client to get pricing for the list of SKUs
- when customer purchases something using google's billing sdk, you'll get a purchase receipt object
- send your purchase receipt to your server

Server:

- the server will validate the purchase receipt with Google, where the server itself makes an API call to google to verify the authenticity of the receipt
- if the receipt succeeds, the server returns a success code

App:

- if the response from sending the receipt succeeds, then you make a new request to the billing SDK, this time to fulfill the purchase (close the transaction)
- when fulfillment succeeds, call your server to notify that fulfillment is completed. send the lenght of the subscription (monthly, yearly...)

Server:

- grant access to the subscription content the user just purchased
- when the renewal time is up (which came from the fulfillment call), your server wakes up and calls google to renew the subscription
- if renewal succeeds, user continues to have access to the subscription content

Yes, this is A LOT more work, but it is also dramatically more resilient and future proof than having a true/false flag in your app.

With that being said, if your subscriptions are $1 a year, and you expect to have no more than 10 users...then do the quick and easy way.

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer!

Comment: I'll try to inform myself about client-server-architectures, since I don't have any experience with this.

I understand the concept you explain, but I do not have any idea how to realize it.
I'd be very thankful if you have some examples I can have a look at!

And, all in all, you also recommend to only upload a `mock-google-services.json` to my public repo?

Comment: Mmm billing/commerce is something that's often very specific to your organization, so sharing some code is both a security concern, and perhaps even useless for you.

Comment: Also, this whole commerce flow is something you have to really understand - not just copy someone else's setup. Why? It'll break or must be updated under a certain deadline. If you don't know how to do it you'll be in a much worse spot than not having it

Comment: My personal suggestion is you delegate the process between 2 teams/people. One owns the back end and one owns the Android/front end. Getting this working is hard and tedious, but doable. Debugging it, maintaining it, research issues, and fixing it is a very hard thing to do - specially for a full team of 1. Example: if a customer tells you in 3 months that they've been paying you but they haven't received the content what do you do? Where's the issue? Who researches what? Is it a real issue or is the customer lying? How many other customers have this issue? What do you change to fix this?